# Prove that ${3^{2}}^{n} + 1$ when divided by $2^{2}$, always gives a remainder of 2, where $n$ is a natural number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$P(n)=3^{{2}^{n}} + 1$

$P(1)=3^{{2}^{1}} + 1$

$P(1)=10=4*2+2$

$P(2)=3^{{2}^{2}} + 1$

$P(2)=82=4*20+2$

...

...

...

$P(k)=3^{{2}^{k}} + 1$

Comment: This is number theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\displaystyle{3^{2^n}=(2+1)^{2^n}}$. This will leave a remainder of $1$ when divided by $2^2$. And the expression you have is $$\displaystyle{3^{2^n}+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $3\equiv -1\pmod 4$, $3^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and so $3^{2^n}\equiv \left(3^2\right)^{2^{(n-1)}}\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $3^{2^n}+1\equiv 2\pmod 4$.  There's also an easy inductive proof of the statement that $3^{2^n}\equiv 1\pmod 4$ for $n\geq 1$: the statement is true in the case $n=1$ by inspection ($3^{2^1} =3^2=9\equiv 1\pmod 4$), and if it's true for $n$ then $3^{2^{n+1}} = \left(3^{2^n}\right)^2 \equiv 1^2\equiv 1\pmod 4$, (using the result for $n$ in the middle equivalency), so it's true for $n+1$.

But be careful — your last two statements are '$P(k) = 3^{2^k}+1$' and '$P(k) = 9^k+1$', and these are *not* equivalent; $\left(a^b\right)^c\neq a^{\left(b^c\right)}$, and by convention when we write $a^{b^c}$ we mean $a^{\left(b^c\right)}$ (since $\left(a^b\right)^c$ is just $a^{bc}$).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$3^{2^1}+1=2^2\times 2+2$$ and suppose that there exist an integer $k$ such that $$3^{2^n}+1=4k+2.$$ Then
$$3^{2^{n+1}}+1=3^{2.2^n}+1=(3^{2^n})^2+1=(4k+1)^2+1=4(4k^2+2k)+2.$$ Hence by mathematical induction we have your result.